Unable to copy or move file from databases folder with RNFS in react native
I have my database created at /data/data/<app_packagename>/databases/dbfile  by react-native-sqlite-storage
i can see this file with Android Studio device explorer and the db works fine
i need to access this path by RNFS to copie the file but i get
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory
I tried:
RNFS.copyFile(path, destPath).then(() => { console.log('successfu')})

And
adding the permissions :
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


I found a solution for this problem that i was facing lately too
I solved the problem by guaranteeing the access and adding a control
like this :


  var path_dbMaster="/data/user/0/com.<name_your_package>/databases/db_name"
  var path_dbCopie=RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath+'/dbCopie.db'

  const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, );
       if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED)
        {   
          
          RNFS.copyFile(path_dbMaster,path_dbCopie)  
          .then(result => {  
            console.log('file copied:', result);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
          });
        
         } 
        else {      
           console.log('not granted');     
           
           Alert.alert(''," Permission required ",[{
            text:'OK',
            style:'cancel'
           }])

          } 



and by adding the permissions in androidManifest
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

and add
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in <application .. > of AndroidManifest
